# Why is CSS height:100% not working in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have an IE6 absolute position `div` that I want to be full screen (100% width and height). It's being used as a "loading, please wait" message while the data loads on the page.

It appears that ie6 does not recognize the css of `"height:100%"`.

Any work arounds?

Comment: I feel for you with the IE6 quirks. Fortunately, this problem has an answer. But a lot of times the answer is just "because it's IE6."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also, in some older browsers you need to set the height of the html tag as well:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Height 100% on a div needs it's parent to also have a height defined in IE6.  Try this:

```
body{
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, and this might have flaws of its own, you could do the following:

```
#fullScreenDiv {position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
}
```

It'll maybe screw with nested components and their floats and so forth, but it would definitely, with a doctype, make the div full screen.